# check if one big string contains another string using NSPredicate or regular expression

Tags: ios, nspredicate

```
NSString *string = @"A long term stackoverflow.html";
NSString *expression = @"stack(.*).html";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", expression];

BOOL match = [predicate evaluateWithObject:string]
if(match){
    NSLog(@"found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

how can i search if expression is present in string or not. above code is working for one word. but not if i put some more words in string to be searched

Comment: pattern should be `content BEGINSWITH[c] %@`

Comment: @iPatel- can u explain your comment or can write as answer

Comment: @John I have edited my answer. Please take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to check a string with a regex value then you should use `NSRegularExpression` not `NSPredicate`.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"stack(.*).html" options:0 error:nil];
```

Then you can use the functions to find matches...

```
NSString *string = @"stackoverflow.html";

NSUInteger matchCount = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

NSLog(@"Number of matches = %d", matchCount);
```

Note: I'm terrible at creating regex patterns so I have just used your pattern and example. I have no idea if the pattern will actually find a match in this string but if there is a match it will work.

Comment: @fogmeister- error-no visible interface for options, while using your code, also i have updated my question what excatly i want

Comment: @John In which line? I'm not using Xcode here so I don't have code completion. When using Xcode you have the added advantage of code completion to fix typos I might make,

Comment: @John No worries. Happy to help :) glad it worked for you in the end.

Answer (score 1):

`NSPredicate` only matches complete strings, so you should change your pattern to cover the whole string:

```
NSString    *expression = @".*stack(.*).html.*";
```

However, your original pattern will also match something like "stack my files high as html", so you may want to read up on your regex patterns.

Comment: @Monolo- how to check that it is present or not

Comment: @John that information is what your boolean variable `match` contains.

Answer (score -1):

Improve your question , but see below answer for your question

```
 NSString *string = @"This is the main stringsss which needs to be searched for some text the texts can be any big. let us see";
 if ([string rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) {
 NSLog(@"string does not contains");
 } else {
 NSLog(@"string contains !");
 }
```

Comment: @John there is no question to read. You've just put a statement and some code.

Comment: @John give your question clearly and expect the right answer from other , dont start giving your comments before giving a proper question....